# Method called by Web UI doesn't returns results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm confused, I have this method:

```
        public IEnumerable<ProfessionalModel> GetAllProfessionals()
        {
            return Context.ProfessionalContext
                .Include(x => x.UserAccountModel)
                .Include(x => x.UserAddressModel).ToList();
        }
```

If I call it using a console UI it return one record (it works), but If I call it using my MVC application it returns no one record!

Console UI:

```
        ProfessionalContext pcontext = new ProfessionalContext();
        var list = pcontext.GetAllProfessionals();
        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

MVC Web UI:

```
    public class ProfessionalController : Controller
    {
        public ProfessionalContext professionalContext { get; set; }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            professionalContext = new ProfessionalContext();

            var professionals = professionalContext.GetAllProfessionals();

            if (professionals == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(professionals);
        }
    }
```

And the problem is not at View, because I've debugged it and the var `professionals` have no records.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

My Context:

```
public class TCCDatabase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserAccountModel> UserAccountContext { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProfessionalModel> ProfessionalContext { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserAddressModel> UserAddressContext { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the return type is

```
IEnumerable<ProfessionalModel>
```

which means your debugger may sometimes not display the elements in the list till you ask it to evaluate.

Double check there are no records in the **professionals** variable as follows:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        professionalContext = new ProfessionalContext();

        var professionals = professionalContext.GetAllProfessionals();

        Debug.Assert(professionals != null && professionals.Any());

        if (professionals == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(professionals);
    }
```

And if you want to see the results instantly in debugger etc. do this:

```
public List<ProfessionalModel> GetAllProfessionals() { //body }
```

Comment: actually that was a pretty basic error, my connection string was with a little mistake, I've corrected it, and now it is working!